# Trying to insert an input into a file, but having a ''NoneType' object is not iterable" error'

Tags: python

I'm trying to get an input from the user and put that input into the file in its proper location.

Here is what I have done so far ( Names.txt has a list of first names in alphabetical order and I don't want any duplicates so I converted list into set)

```
def main():
    outfile = open("Names.txt","a")
    list1 = []
    name1 = 0
    name1 = input("Enter a name, if you want to quit, enter q: ")
    while name1 != "q":
        list1 = list1.append(name1)
        outfile.writelines(list1)
    list1.sort()
    s = set(list1)
    return s
main()
```

but I am having a problem whenever I input something other than q.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\SKKU\Desktop\1.py", line 12, in <module>
    main()
 File "C:\Users\SKKU\Desktop\1.py", line 8, in main
    outfile.writelines(list1)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

What am I supposed to do about it?
Am I doing it right?

Comment: hint: `list1.append(...)` returns None.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

another pointer, there is no use in declaring name1 = 0

```
    name1 = 0   #you can remove this
    name1 = input("Enter a name, if you want to quit, enter q: ")
    while name1 != "q":
        list1 = list1.append(name1)
        outfile.writelines(list1)
```

additionally, your while loop is writing lines to your file indefinitely,

You are indicating your program to append name1 to your list, then write something that makes no sense to your file as mentioned by @Blorgbeard
So there are several things you might want to rewrite/remove in your code.

you might want to consider reading a bit on List manipulations (http://effbot.org/zone/python-list.htm) and using a for loop :

```
list = [#items]
for item in list: #instead of a while loop
#do something 
    print item
```

Answer (score 1):

The line to add a name to the list should be just:

```
list1.append(name1)
```

Because `append` modifies the existing list, and doesn't return anything (i.e. returns `None`).

Hence, you were setting `list1` to `None` with `list1 = list1.append(name1)`. Then you passed `None` to `outfile.writelines`, which tried to iterate over the thing you passed, which of course, doesn't make sense for `None`.